# left div width 100% increase when right div don't have content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 div both are 50% width and float left what I want if the right div doesn't have content then left div width should be 100%.

```js
if ($('.wrap .box2').is(':empty')) {
  $('.box2').hide();
  $('.wrap .box1').css({
    "width": "100%"
  });
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap .box1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.wrap .box2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Hello 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h1>Hello 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want if .box2 dont have text inside h1 then left div width should be 100%

Comment: Have tried making width auto to both the div?

Comment: @RithikBanerjee both div have background so auto with not going to help

Comment: then I guess jQuery is the solution.

Comment: If box2 doesn't have text in h1 it's not empty, it's h1 is empty. Change the jquery element to `$('.wrap .box2 h1')`

Comment: @Viking your code works perfectly if `box2` is empty. Note that empty means no textnodes and whitespace (for code indention) either.

Comment: @MarkBaijens right but the left div lot get 100% width

Comment: @nirshabi I want to left div 100% if right div doesn't have text right now right is hiding and left div to remain 50% width

Comment: @Viking I can not reproduce that with your code. When I remove everything in the `.box2` element including whitespace then box1 will have a width of 100%. Should it skip checking on whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if ($('.wrap .box2 h1').is(':empty')) {
  $('.box2').hide();
  $('.wrap .box1').css({
    "width": "100%"
  });
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap .box1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.wrap .box2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Hello 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just ran this code and the left div took the whole space

Comment: Thanks, my bad in my actual code replaced the h1 with h2  :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrap .box1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.wrap .box2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.wrap .box2:empty {
  width: 0;
}
```

it works without using javascript/jquery and uses flex-boxes and the :empty selector.

Comment: Sure I tested it, have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/89p0n2xt/

Comment: Yes that will work if you omit the <h1> element, but the case here that <h1> exists with no text...

Comment: Yeah I was going with the "right div doesn't have content " thing from OP. Of course if you need to have an h1 within that itself does not have a content, then you cannot use that approach. Because there's no :has() selector - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has